# Trying to connect to Redis returns an ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: webapp
    env_file: .env.docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  mongo:
    image: "mongo"
```

And I'm using the following env variables to connect to Mongo and Redis

```
REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/webapp
```

With this configuration, when the app starts it can connect to the Mongo container, but it fails to connect to Redis with the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I tried exposing and mapping the ports:

```
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

but it still doesn't solve the issue. Mapping the ports I can use redis-cli to connect to Redis, so I know the container is running.

Any clues?

EDIT: Running the webapp on my machine without Docker works normally. I tried both, native Redis and Mongo as well as running with the `docker-compose` below commenting out the `web` section and mapping the ports.

EDIT 2: Output of `lsof`

```
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 3136 JayC   20u  IPv4 0x7dac4a08aadc94c9      0t0  TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)
com.docke 3136 JayC   21u  IPv6 0x7dac4a08bbf50781      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
```

EDIT 3: Adding where the app connects to Redis:

```
const { RedisPubSub } = require('graphql-redis-subscriptions');

console.log(`-------------- REDIS_URL: ${process.env.REDIS_URL} --------------`);

const engine = new RedisPubSub({
    connection: {
        url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
    },
    connectionListener: err => {
        if (err) {
            Logger.sys.error(
                `redis connection failed at ${process.env.REDIS_URL}`,
            );
            Logger.sys.error(err);
        } else {
            Logger.sys.info(
                `pubsub connected to redis at ${process.env.REDIS_URL}`,
            );
        }
    },
});
```

The log output:

```
-------------- REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379 --------------
2018-06-05T13:21:37.658Z - error: redis connection failed at redis://redis:6379
2018-06-05T13:21:37.659Z - error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379 }
```

Comment: Is there is anything running on 6379 port ? Check by this command `sudo lsof -i tcp:6379`

Comment: Yes, it's running. I can actually connect to the Redis container from my machine, just not from the web container. `lsof` shows 6379 open on both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: Maybe kill that port anh run `docker-compose up` again will work. Kill port by `sudo kill -9 Your_PID`. Or  just simly `docker-compose down --volumses` and up again...

Comment: I've restarted the containers many times already, making sure that the port is closed, and it's still not working...

Comment: Seem weird, your port 6379 is running, that mean Redis working...

Comment: Even weirder. I can run the same docker-compose commenting out the `web` service, run that service natively on my machine (outside Docker) and it works.

Comment: It might be a matter of timing because everything looks fine. Try using depends_on to control the order of service startup.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: I pretty sure that your 6379 port aready in use by your native Redis... `docker-compose down`, `sudo lsof -i tcp:6379` kill that port `sudo kill -9 you_PID_ID`. Run `sudo lsof -i tcp:6379` again to make sure there is nothing using that port. `docker-compose up` again.. I really think that wrok

Comment: @TruongDang There's nothing else listening on that port. When I do `docker-compose down` (or `ctrl+c`) there is nothing else on that port, so `docker-compose up` always starts with all necessary ports available and I can actually use redis-cli to connect to the Redis container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The configuration you described is not being used by your application:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
```

When you see the connection run, it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of the container ip:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

To solve this, you'll need to reconfigure your app so that it uses the redis DNS name instead of 127.0.0.1. Each container has its own private loopback interface, so connecting to this inside a container will connect to the container itself, not your host or any other container running on the host.

As an aside, do not use links. They have been deprecated. The built in DNS will give name resolution to the service name. If you have dependencies between containers, it's best to handle this in the application or entrypoint. You can also use `depends_on` to list service dependencies, but this only works with docker-compose, and does not verify the health of the dependent services.

Comment: It also looked strange to me, but the call to connect to Redis actually uses the env variable. I logged the variable I use on connect, just in case, and it shows the right value.

Comment: Why do you feel your application is connecting to a different address than the logs indicate, do your logs have the wrong address being output? Seems more likely that the application is not connecting to where you think it's connecting. A [mcve] of your application showing it try to connect to redis by DNS and log the above line would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I finally figured out why it was not working. I added the call to my question so the answer is clear. The `connection` attribute passed to the RedisPubSub constructor was wrong, and it was defaulting to `redis://localhost:6379` which works locally but not on Docker.

Answer (score 4):

It have worked on me when I have changed REDIS_URL to:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://redis
```